# Angular application breaks after using facebook connect plugin in cordova

Tags: angular, facebook, cordova

When I try to redirect to another page after running facebook connect plugin`s login method, angular freezes and does nothing.

I have tried everything and have no idea why a cordova plugin breaks angular.

When I execute:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], (x) => {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
});
```

And redirect to any page, angular does not react in any way, does not run the constructor, ngOnInit none of them.

Edit:
I was able to pin down the problem seems like facebook login dialog is not properly closed after logging in. I can still see it in the chrome Remote target tool. I am able to click on any location in the emulator and the dialog closes and everything starts works. The question becomes how to force facebook plugin to properly close after logging in.

Comment: Not sure why this question got 2 down votes, but  I also had similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use NgZone. Discussion [is here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22509)

Here is the working sample:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// ...

export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router) {}

    navigateTo(routeName: string) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => { this.router.navigate([routeName]); });
    }
}
```